# Setting Privacy Settings using the Facebook API

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, desktop-application, privacy

I am working with the Facebook API for C#. I am unable to find any reference to changing privacy settings using the API. I've looked at a lot of different places, with no success.

Could anyone guide me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Only through the official channels can users change their privacy settings.

Comment: With the exception of the "Post" object which does have a "privacy" field http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ ... The value field may specify one of the following strings: EVERYONE, ALL_FRIENDS, NETWORKS_FRIENDS, FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS, CUSTOM .

Comment: Yeh, you really can't change privacy settings, and that is for good reasons. For privacy settings, it is best to have a webBrowser and point it to facebook.com's privacy settings page.

Comment: @pathachiever11 for good reasons? I'd love to hear a good reason why your application shoudn't be able to allow the user to post a photo into an album of his and have only some given friends see it.

Comment: @matteo - i wouldn't want a spammy app to post 100s of pictures without permission nor open up previously private posts.

Comment: You wouldn't want a spammy app to post 100 of posts on your wall either. Does that mean that the api shouldn't expose the ability to post on the user's wall?? That's what permissions are for.

Comment: also note that you _can_ choose the privacy settings when you post to /me/feed, so why on earth shouldn't you be able to do the same when uploading a photo into an album. Ok that's not the same as _changing_ the privacy setting of an existing item, but it's another thing that there's no good reason why you can't do.

Comment: If you don't think so, you can go ahead and post a ticket on the Facebook developer site. They will further answer your questions, and possibly give you an alternative.